# keydown listener 1 character off?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I've got the following...

a textfield `tbox` and an event listener like so...

```
 tbox.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
        q = event.target.value;
        alert("q = " + q);
 }, false);
```

My problem is that if I type for example `a` alert tells me q is `""` then if I type another letter b it tells me q is `a`. etc. etc. being 1 character off each time. Does anyone know how I'd fix this? I'm testing with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing "keydown" to "keyup".

Comment: That worked! very, very strange. You don't know why that causes a problem do you?

Comment: This is because when you use "keydown" the event is fired BEFORE the character is added to your text field. It's a keyboard related event, it happens when the user starts pressing a key. "keyup" happens when the user releases the key.